# SSH on port 80 or 443 does not work

Tags: networking, ssh, google-cloud-platform

I'm on a network which blocks all ports except 80 and 443. So, I'm trying to setup my remote machine to listen on port 80 or 443 (obviously done through some other network) but here's what I get:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine dev@mymachine -p 80
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

ssh -i ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine dev@mymachine -p 443
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

I already edited my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and added `Port 80` and `Port 443` under `Port 22` and restarted the ssh service as well. What am I missing here?

Also, mymachine is a machine hosted on **google cloud compute engine**.

Comment: Post the debug log with `-vvv` switches. Maybe the gateway is somehow filtering even the HTTP traffic?

Comment: @Jakuje I've tried with multiple Internet connections (the ones which allow all traffic as well). Looks like a problem from server side. I'll post the logs soon

Comment: @Jakuje I didn't check "Allow HTTP Traffic" while creating Google cloud instance. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Facing the same problem! I think there's some sort of a filtering application running on top of the machine. I tried making SSHD listen on non-standard ports (say 8040) but couldn't SSH into that port either.

sudo service ssh status and sshd logs clearly say that the daemon is listening on all the ports mentioned in sshd_config! This seems like a compute-engine specific problem. They don't hand over complete control to the user.